# my .htaccess is not working on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, ubuntu

RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /cpmsystem/

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/{2,}([^\s]*)
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)/{2,}[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} system|application
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

#

my .htaccess is not working, can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my codes?

#

Comment: what are the error your spacing ?

Comment: it is being redirected on a different page. for example my local site is http://localhost/sitename/ but instead of going to that url the links goes to here www.localhost.com/sitename/index.php

Comment: are you change the base_url in config file ?

Comment: here is my config


$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sitename';

Comment: are you remove index.php in config file ?

Comment: yes i did that already

Comment: by the way i also activatedd the mod_rewrite but still nothing is working